# How can I get the Changing Data Values from website with Beautiful Soup?

Tags: python, beautifulsoup

I am trying web **scraping** with BeautifulSoup for getting data of BTC-USDT from biance. Actually I am getting what I want but the value is changing in every second in website,but when I am trying to print it to my console it prints me same value and it change rarely. Basically, my data are the same every time when I try to get it, but on the website, it changes every time and I can't get that changing data.
What can I do?

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import requests
import time



while(True):
    url='https://www.binance.com/tr/trade/BTC_USDT'
    HTML=requests.get(url)
    html_content=HTML.content
    soup=BeautifulSoup(HTML.text,'html.parser')
    paper=str((soup.find('title',attrs={'data-shuvi-head':'true'})))
    print(paper)
    time.sleep(5)
```

Comment: modern pages use `JavaScript` to update data but `BeautifulSoup` can't run `JavaScript` and you may need to use [Selenium](https://selenium-python.readthedocs.io/) to control real web browser which can run javascript. But first check if `binance` has `API` so you could get data as JSON without scraping page.

Comment: [Binance API](https://binance-docs.github.io/apidocs/spot/en/#general-info)

Comment: Okey I will try that.Thanks for help

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This page uses `JavaScript` to update data but `BeautifulSoup` can't run `JavaScript`. You use need [Selenium](https://selenium-python.readthedocs.io/) to control real web browser which can run `JavaScript`.

```
from selenium import webdriver
import time
             
url = 'https://www.binance.com/tr/trade/BTC_USDT'  # PEP8: spaces around `=`

#driver = webdriver.Chrome()
driver = webdriver.Firefox()
driver.get(url)

while True:  # PEP8: no need `()`
    try:
        #print(driver.title)
        print(driver.title.split(' ')[0].strip())
    except Exception as ex:
        print('Exception:', ex)
        
    time.sleep(5)
```

---

Eventually you can check in `DevTools` (tab `Network`) in `Chrome`/`Firefox` to see url used by `JavaScript` to get new data - and then you can try to use it with `requests`. Because `JavaScript` usually send data as `JSON` so you will no need `BeautifulSoup` but module `json`.

But first check if you can get it with official [Binance API](https://binance-docs.github.io/apidocs/spot/en/#general-info)

---

[PEP 8 -- Style Guide for Python Code](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-008/)

---

**EDIT**

Example with Binance API: [Current Average Price](https://binance-docs.github.io/apidocs/spot/en/#current-average-price)

```
import requests
import time

url = 'https://api.binance.com/api/v3/avgPrice?symbol=BTCUSDT'

while True:
    response = requests.get(url)
    data = response.json() 
    print(data['price'])
    
    time.sleep(5)
```

Comment: That's really what I am looking for.Thank you so much!

Comment: I added example with Binance API. It gives average price for 5 minutes,

Comment: I need current data of them.The first one is enough but thank you for showing that way too.

Comment: Is there a way for I can get current data of them with using json?Or It just let to get average data?

Comment: I don't know. There is so many functions in API and you would have to check if one of them gives expected data. Maybe it will need to use `websocket` instead of `requests`. Or maybe it needs extra options like. OR maybe you should use special module [python-binance](https://python-binance.readthedocs.io/en/latest/)